# New ASP.Net MVC3 project, won't load files from Scripts folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I just created a new ASP.Net MVC3 project, and it won't load any scripts from the Scripts folder, gives me a 404 when I debug.

How in the world do I fix this?

included like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
```

or using a Global variable in App_Code like this:

```
public static readonly string JSDir = "../../Scripts";
```

In my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@GlobalVal.JSDir/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@GlobalVal.JSDir/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@GlobalVal.JSDir/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@GlobalVal.JSDir/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@GlobalVal.JSDir/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
```

Tried this, too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-transition.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-alert.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-modal.js")"></script>
```

Either way, same result. 404 for all files in Scripts folder.

Comment: Do you include them in your view? How about a code sample.

Comment: What [Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) are you getting.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:55578/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js

Comment: What happens when you load the resource directly in the browser... because it sounds like this has nothing to do with MVC nor HTML, but a problem your resources or iis configuration.

Comment: The server in VS won't load it, gives 404.

Comment: Then the file doesn't exist.  It's pure and simple.  Unless you changed it, by default existing files are served directly by the browser, bypassing the asp.net pipeline.

Comment: Not if you are debugging, it goes through the VS web server. Not sure how, because I see it in BOTH Explorer and Project Explorer.

Comment: Ok, finally figured it out. Somehow a Web.config file got placed in that folder and it had the httphandler section that blocks serving anything from that folder. WHEW!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Web.config file had been placed in that directory that had the http handler to block serving anything from that folder.